# How to run Node.js server in Ionic mobile app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making an app using MEAN and ionic framework where nodejs is a middleware to connect to the database(mongoDb). I need to run the nodejs server using `node server.js` and the app using `ionic serve`. This is my server.js.

```
var express          = require('express'),
app              = express(),
bodyParser       = require('body-parser'),
mongoose         = require('mongoose'),
CohortController =require('./www/server/controller/CohortController');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/persistent');

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/api/cohorts',CohortController.list);
app.post('/api/cohorts',CohortController.create);

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log('Listening...');
})
```

Now this is my app.js. I use `http://localhost:3000` to get the JSON.

```js
app.controller('CohortController',['$scope','$resource',
  function($scope,$resource){
    var Cohort=$resource('http://localhost:3000/api/cohorts');
    Cohort.query(function(results){
      $scope.cohorts=results;
    });
    $scope.cohorts=[];

    $scope.createCohort= function () {
      var cohort=new Cohort();
      cohort.name=$scope.CohortName;
      cohort.id=$scope.CohortId;
      cohort.$save(function(result){
        $scope.cohorts.push(result);
        $scope.CohortName='';
        $scope.CohortId='';
      });
    }
  }]);
```

How can I run the node server when I convert it into a mobile application? How the application will use the API?

Comment: Will you run mongodb on your mobile server too ?

Comment: I will use mongolab to host the mongdb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to have your Node.js app running on a server which you would then access (from your Ionic app) via it's public IP. So, you wouldn't use `http://localhost:3000` to get the JSON, instead you would use something like `http://123.456.789.123:3000`.

But, usually, this is not the way you would do it (with the port 3000). What you would additionally do is put (for example) Nginx in front of your Node.js app ([see an example here](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/nodejs/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-in-front-of-your-node-js-application/)) in order to serve your api from the standard HTTP port (80).

So, basically, you can't actually "run Node.js server in Ionic app" - the way you do it is run the Node.js app separate from Ionic and expose its functionality via a standardized API (usually these days [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is what you would want to achieve) which you then "consume" via Ionic's (well, to be exact, it's actually Angular's) [$resource module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Hope this helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: I might need to ask this as another question. Lets say I want the node API/Server to allow calls from the ionic app running on someones phone and a web site (example.com). It sounds like I need to enable CORS, but I don’t want to open it up to attacks so from reading, it sounds like we don’t want to do: ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’. If I just wanted the website I would do ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘example.com’. From your answer I am still unsure how to allow calls from phones running the ionic app.

Comment: @Beastwood: you would "simply" create REST api for your Node app, and that's it. I've put simply in quotes since it's not that "easy", but then again, it's not rocket science also.

Comment: thanks, but I am still confused how you specify the access-control-allow-origin for the ionic app.

Comment: But, erm, that's the thing - you don't. Why would you? If you want to make the API available only to "some" users, introduce a `key`which you would send with every request. You may have confused these things with Allowing  access origin when testing locally.

Comment: In prod I've to run the ionic on port 80, so how do  we go about having both the node and ionic on port 80, whats the solution to this ?  ( i don't care about the ports but how to get it done ) ?

Comment: I did what @Nicola suggested but im getting  "Provisional Headers Shown" error message.   Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can't. Serve the node api on some other port and consume it with ionic app which will run on port 80. OK, to be totally honest there probably is a way that you'll serve the whole ionic www from express, but then again I haven't seen people do it like that so I couldn't help with that.

Comment: @Nikola, How do we secure the key if we use a key to access the API? Ionic is front end and to make an api call the key has to be somewhere in there. Is there a way to secure it?

Comment: @Tashi in that case you would probably wanna use something like a jwt. Or, some kind of a short-lived token (which you'd get after a successful login) which you'd "refresh".